# Can YouTube safety mode be configured to survive a browser history clear?

Tags: google-chrome, security, browser, youtube

I turned on YouTube's safety mode and set it to "Lock this Browser". Despite [the text I found on Google's support site](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/174084?hl=en), the lock does not seem to work:

> Safety mode is enabled on a browser level, so you must enable it for each browser you use on your computer. If your browser supports multiple profiles you must enable it for each profile.
>
> Once enabled, Safety mode will remain on regardless of whether you are logged in or not, or if another person is logged into a different YouTube account.
>
> If you remain logged in to the YouTube account which locked Safety mode other users of the computer will be able to adjust this setting. To ensure that this lock is not tampered with, you will have to logout the account that enabled Safety mode.

I have been able to defeat safety mode simply by clicking "Clear all browsing data..." and selecting all options, and then restarting the browser.

This doesn't seem very secure. Is there a way to keep the safety mode activated?

Comment: What OS is this? It's possible, but one way to do it depends on the OS.

Comment: Windows 8.1 is the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way YouTube safety mode works is via a browser cookie attached to the HTTP request. There are two basic ways to force it: you can force Chrome to send it via Group Policy/other management systems, or you can add it directly via a proxy (note: using a proxy *also* likely will require using policy management, to keep users from changing proxy settings).

To set up policies for Chrome, check out [this Google site](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202?hl=en&ref_topic=2936229). On Windows, you download an administrative template for Group Policy, which gives you an option to force SafeSearch (which also forces Safety Mode). This can be enabled on a user-by-user basis, or for everyone on the computer. On Mac, you use Managed Preferences, which I'm not quite certain how to do. On Linux, you modify a file in `/etc`. Of course, this is useless if the other users use an account with the necessary administrative privileges to modify Group Policy, but if they do you can't really restrict them anyway.

Another way is to use a [supervised user](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3463947?hl=en), which is Chrome's built-in parental controls system. Supervised users are managed from your Google account, can't install extensions, and can have SafeSearch forced (among other things). To do that, add a new profile to Chrome, and check the box saying "manage with my account." You'll have to sign out of your profile before letting supervised users use the computer, or else they can switch to an unrestricted profile. You'll probably also have to disable guest browsing for Chrome, again to stop them from accessing an unsupervised account. This is somewhat more fragile than using Group Policy, because unlike with Group Policy, you aren't using the OS's user system (which is designed to keep users from accessing other users' stuff). However, it is easier to set up.

You can also use a proxy, and force Chrome to browse through that proxy; the proxy can be made to add the Safety Mode cookie.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to spend some time on your answer to see if it works. Your final paragraph is interesting. Which proxy, and how would you configure it?

Comment: @Kit That would probably be harder than forcing SafeSearch; as far as I can tell, the proxy settings involves rewriting the `PREF` cookie to append `&f2=8000000`, and requires a somewhat advanced proxy (to intercept the HTTPS YouTube connections).